# App Store - App Privacy - Can't update app privacy questions as admin

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Since yesterday, a new privacy policy is enforced when submitting your app for reviewing on the App Store through App Store Connect. Before yesterday, I was able to submit my app, but today, I get the following error:

> Before you can submit this app for review, an Admin must provide information about the app’s privacy practices in the App Privacy section. Learn more.

When I go to General -> App Privacy, I get the following message:

> [...] Account Holders and Admins are responsible for disclosing what data is collected from this app and how it may be used.

According to [this guide](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1b4647c5b) (step 3), a 'get started' button should appear leading to a page where I should be able to answer privacy questions. However, this button does not appear. It seems that I am not able to answer these questions anywhere else, even though my role is `admin`. Does anybody else encounter the same issue? Am I overlooking something?

Note that I've been promoted to `admin` only minutes ago. It could be that my role is not yet propagated to the privacy section, but the rest of app connect does reflect my new role correctly, so it does not look like it's not propagated.

Answer (score 39):

I just had to click "Publish" in the top right corner.

I thought this was to publish the app, but it was actually to publish the privacy policy that I'd already filled out. The other sections didn't have a special "Publish" button, so this was confusing.

Comment: It cracks me up that this has gotten so many upvotes all because Apple is bad at web UI.

Comment: You're indeed a life saver and definitely you must enjoy the reputation

Answer (score 17):

I also faced this issue.

The solution is, we need to provide some information in App Privacy menu.[image]

Comment: Yea I didn't see what you're seeing right now, I wasn't able to do anything at all related there. After a while it did show up though.

Comment: In App Privacy menu there will be Get Started Button bro. You should click that button bro then you will be taken over with some pages to add your permissions

Answer (score 3):

In the App Privacy section there is "Get Started" button that did't appear to me because I wasn't the holder or admin of that account.

Answer (score 2):

Got it fixed by selecting App Information / Edit User Access, setting Full Access, and then I logged out and logged in again.

Comment: I have full access as well as admin role but i can’t see publish button enabled

Answer (score 2):

If you're use any ads in your app you must select that you collect data via your app in your App Privacy and then select which data you collect like user location. You may have also add other data if your app collect those data. Yesterday i upload an application and its live now.

First select Yes in `App Privacy`

[image]

Then add which data you collect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing same issues. Finally resolved issue select Analytics and **USER Tracking option**. I think, Apple force to user to select Tracking user option in App Privacy. I'm not using anything tracking, AD BUT Apple forcefully allow to select **USER Tracking option**. I have registered appeal to Apple... :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just need to fill all the details in App Privacy section & hit publish button on right top corner.  You can submit your builds after this step.

Comment: Publish button is not enabled for me, even in account holder login

Comment: The publish button also is grayed out for me. Nothing seems to enable it. @GokulG did you ever figure out how to fix that issue?

Comment: from account holder login raised a customer support ticket to Apple and with their support managed to resolved it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by asking my Administrator to set my account as Admin role, then after few minutes (refresh page) the blue buttons appeared itself and I can complete the privacy questions. Please don't forget to click on "Publish" (on the top right corner) after you finish filling the form.

Comment: He is already an admin. Also, it will be better if you can attach some screenshots to show the reference for the blue button you mentioned.

Comment: was missing the publish button clicking bit. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to App Privacy and Click on Apply

On the Right Top Corner

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forget to press **Publish** inside the App privacy section.

Make sure to press Publish Privacy policy in the top right **before** press **Add for review**

Comment: This was the solution for me also.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be a propagation issue after all. Problem solved itself an hour later.

Comment: hey Jaap how you resolved this issue, Still I am facing this issue

Comment: I was promoted to admin and after an hour the button presented itself

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue..and solution is go to -> App Privacy -> Product page review and data Types and set according to your app uses or you can set Data is not collected from this app.
Don't forget to save changes pr proceed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF3U0.png)